# pass message between Processors in order

Tags: c, mpi

I am trying to write an MPI program, and the purpose of it is to pass a message between processors
for example
assuming that there are 4 processors 
processor 0 should send the message to processor 1
processor 1 should send the message to processor 2
processor 2 should send the message to processor 3
processor 3 should send the message to processor 0
processor 0 should send the message to processor 1
....
and so on
what is the best way to ensure that processor 1 keep waiting till it receives the message from processor 0....etc

Comment: `MPI_Recv` maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv` operations are sufficient to implement this. You can easily find documentation online, e.g., that of [MPI_Recv of openMPI](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_Recv.3.php). Your basic algorithm looks like this: Every process calls `MPI_Recv`. This blocks (or "waits") until a matching message is received; then, us `MPI_Send` to send the message to the next process. To kick off this merry-go-around, you'll need process 0 to send a message before calling `MPI_Recv`.